fill NAs with set of preceding values
I have a dataframe that looks like this:
d = data.frame(obs = 1:4, comp = c("7_10","5","6_9","1_2_6_9"))

  obs    comp
1   1    7_10
2   2       5
3   3     6_9
4   4 1_2_6_9

The comp column contains information about the elements that can be found in each observation (row). So, the first observation contains the elements 7 and 10, the second, element 5 and so on. Each observation can contain one, two or four out of the possible 10 elements.
I can separate these into distinct columns:
library(tidyverse)
d %>% 
  separate_wider_delim(comp, 
                       delim = "_", 
                       names = c("e1", "e2", "e3", "e4"),
                       too_few = "align_start")

    obs e1    e2    e3    e4   
1     1 7     10    NA    NA   
2     2 5     NA    NA    NA   
3     3 6     9     NA    NA   
4     4 1     2     6     9  

However, instead of NAs, I need the information to repeat, like this:
    obs e1    e2    e3    e4   
1     1 7     10    7     10   # elements 7 and 10 repeat
2     2 5     5     5     5    # element 5 repeats
3     3 6     9     6     9   
4     4 1     2     6     9 

I know how to use pivot_longer and fill to fill in NAs with the preceding value:
d %>% 
  separate_wider_delim(comp, 
                       delim = "_", 
                       names = c("e1", "e2", "e3", "e4"),
                       too_few = "align_start") %>% 
  pivot_longer(2:5,
               names_to = "e",
               values_to = "code") %>% 
  fill(code, .direction = "down") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = e,
              values_from = code)

    obs e1    e2    e3    e4   
1     1 7     10    10    10  
2     2 5     5     5     5    
3     3 6     9     9     9    
4     4 1     2     6     9   

Is there a way to instead fill NAs with the set of preceding values, instead of just the last value?

The current title is based on how I am trying to achieve this, however there might be a very different way to get from what I have to what I want. Suggestions for a more apt title are welcome

How do you want the replacement to work if you have three values?

@IRTFM fair question. I never have three values. it's 1,2 or 4 elements. I have updated the main text

If you know that comp sequences are either 1, 2, or 4 elements (if 1, then repeat 4 times, if 2 repeat twice, if 4 don't repeat), then you can use rep and indicate a target length for each obs of 4. The row_number is added to show the data in wide format as in the example output above.
library(tidyverse)

d %>% 
  separate_longer_delim(comp, delim = "_") %>%
  reframe(value = rep_len(comp, length.out = 4), .by = obs) %>%
  mutate(name = row_number(), .by = obs) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = obs, names_from = name, values_from = value, names_prefix = "e")

Output
    obs e1    e2    e3    e4   
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 7     10    7     10   
2     2 5     5     5     5    
3     3 6     9     6     9    
4     4 1     2     6     9


In base we could start from
> f = \(l) {
+   stopifnot(is.list(l))
+   nc = max(lengths(l))
+   do.call(rbind, lapply(l, rep, length.out=nc)) 
+ }
> d[-1L] = f(strsplit(d$comp, "_", fixed = TRUE))
> d 
  obs comp.1 comp.2 comp.3 comp.4
1   1      7     10      7     10
2   2      5      5      5      5
3   3      6      9      6      9
4   4      1      2      6      9

Note
Input data
d = data.frame(obs = 1:4, comp = c("7_10","5","6_9","1_2_6_9"))


With base R, you can try read.table + `[<-`like below
cbind(
    d,
    t(
        apply(
            read.table(text = d$comp, sep = "_", fill = TRUE),
            1,
            \(x) `[<-`(x, na.omit(x))
        )
    )
)

such that you will obtain
  obs    comp V1 V2 V3 V4
1   1    7_10  7 10  7 10
2   2       5  5  5  5  5
3   3     6_9  6  9  6  9
4   4 1_2_6_9  1  2  6  9


You could take advantage of data.frame's recycling rule:
f <- function(data) {
  newdata <- data.frame(t(data.frame(strsplit(data$comp, split="_"))))
  data[names(newdata)] <- newdata
  data
}

f(d)


  obs    comp X1 X2 X3 X4
1   1    7_10  7 10  7 10
2   2       5  5  5  5  5
3   3     6_9  6  9  6  9
4   4 1_2_6_9  1  2  6  9


help(data.frame)


Objects passed to data.frame should have the same number of rows, but
atomic vectors (see is.vector), factors and character vectors
protected by I will be recycled a whole number of times if necessary
(including as elements of list arguments).

